# Convergence sequence of functions

Tags: sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = 3x^n + 2x$. For what values of $x$ there exists a
pointwise limit of this sequence as $n → ∞$? For what values of $a ∈ \Bbb R≥0$ this sequence converges uniformly
on $[0; a]$?

So I know the answer for the first part is $x$ element of $[-1;1]$ and the second part is a element $[0;1)$ how do I get there?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Your answer isn't quite correct.  The sequence doesn't converge pointwise at $x=-1$.

Comment: And for the second part, $a=1$ also works.

Comment: how do i get there?